# converting char array to a char constant (c)

Tags: c, arrays, gcc-warning

so im trying to figure out how to change an array to a constant but i keep getting a this error

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing
'char *[3]' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    strcpy(input, inputcon);
           ^~~~~`
```

here is my code

```
int main(void) {

    char *input[3];
    int yn = 0;
    char *no = "no";
    char *inputcon = NULL;
    do {
        printf("This is the game.\nDo you want to play again?\nType y/n: ");
        scanf("%s",*input);
        strcpy(input, inputcon);
        yn = strcmp(inputcon, no);
    } while (yn == 1);
}
```

Comment: `array` to a `constant`??

Comment: Did you even read the man pages of the function you've used?

Comment: You'll need to read up about arrays and pointers before you move on to string handling.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

```
 char *input[3];
```

defines an array of `char` pointers, which you don't *want* here. A simple `char` array will do the job. Change it to

```
char input[4] = {0};   //assuming you want yes to be stored, 
                       // reserve space for terminating null
```

Secondly,

```
 scanf("%s",*input);
```

should be

```
scanf("%3s",input); //limit the input as per the buffer length
```

Third,

```
strcpy(input, inputcon);
```

is entirely unnecessary, Remove it.

Then, you need to replace

```
yn = strcmp(inputcon, no);
```

with

```
yn = strcmp(input, no);
```

That said, you should change the *prompt* to ask user to input *yes* or *no*.

Comment: it still exits no matter what I type.